# Array as search parameter in LINQ query

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Currently I am searching like following

```
resourcesDB.Where(x => x.Resource_Type == 1 && (x.Resource_Ext.ToLower() ==".doc" || (x.Resource_Ext.ToLower() == ".docx"))).ToList();
```

but I want to search records using an array as search parameter, my array is

```
var docExts = new[] { ".pdf",".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx" };
```

I want like

```
resourcesDB.Where(x => x.Resource_Type == 1 && (x.Resource_Ext.ToLower() == [from docExts ])).ToList();
```

Is it possible how can I achieve this?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is specify also that `x.Resource_Ext` is contained in the array:

```
var docExts = new[] { ".pdf",".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx" };

var result = resourcesDB.Where(x => x.Resource_Type == 1 &&     
                                    docExts.Contains(x.Resource_Ext.ToLower());
```

Answer (score 2):

try

```
.Where(x => x.Resource_Type == 1 && docExts.Contains(x.Resource_ext.ToLower()))
```